# RequiredRole, Razor2 and HTML Redirect

Tags: servicestack

I am using ServiceStack with Razor2.

I have decorated one of my services with `RequiredRole("Admin")`.  What I want to happen now is that if I am coming from a browser (Accept=text/html), I want to get an HTML Redirect if I do not have the required role.  Instead I just get a `403 Invalid Role` and the browser just displays a generic error.

Is there a way to achieve what I am after?  I can see the from the source of `RequiredRoleAttribute` that it doesn't seem to allow redirects.

```
 public override void Execute(IHttpRequest req, IHttpResponse res, object requestDto)
    {
        base.Execute(req, res, requestDto); //first check if session is authenticated
        if (res.IsClosed) return; //AuthenticateAttribute already closed the request (ie auth failed)

        var session = req.GetSession();
        if (HasAllRoles(req, session)) return;

        res.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Forbidden;
        res.StatusDescription = "Invalid Role";
        res.EndServiceStackRequest();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have come up with a solution.  I have written my own RoleRequiredCustomAttribute.  It is the same as the `ServiceStack` RoleRequiredAttribute except the execute method looks like this:

```
public override void Execute(IHttpRequest req, IHttpResponse res, object requestDto)
    {
        base.Execute(req, res, requestDto); //first check if session is authenticated
        if (res.IsClosed) return; //AuthenticateAttribute already closed the request (ie auth failed)

        var session = req.GetSession();
        if (HasAllRoles(req, session)) return;

        var htmlRedirect = HtmlRedirect ?? AuthService.HtmlRedirect;
        if (htmlRedirect != null && req.ResponseContentType.MatchesContentType(ContentType.Html))
        {
            var url = req.ResolveAbsoluteUrl(htmlRedirect);
            //url = url.AddQueryParam("redirect", req.AbsoluteUri);
            res.RedirectToUrl(url);
            return;
        }

        res.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Forbidden;
        res.StatusDescription = "Invalid Role";
        res.EndServiceStackRequest();
    }
```

Should I submit a pull request?

Comment: Yep a pull-request would be great (also add it to RequiredPermissions to match). I'll modify it to also look at `Config.CustomHttpHandlers` if there's any rule defined for `HttpStatusCode.Forbidden`.

Comment: @mythz Done - also did it for `RequiresAnyPermission` and `RequiresAnyRole`